# Cannot insert item into array after deleting another item

Tags: java, arrays

I can delete items from my array, but when I try to insert an item it fails on nullpointer exception. This only happens after deleting. Inserting items works normally. 
Thank you in advance.

This determines where to insert the new item so the array stays in order

```
public int appropriatePosition(Comparable ap){
    int temp = top;
    if(temp == -1){
        temp = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        {
            if(ap.compareTo(sa[i])>0)
            {
                temp = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This uses the index that was found in appropriatePostion

```
public void insert(Comparable a){

    int loc = appropriatePosition(a);
    if(full() == true)
    {
        int expandedSize = sa.length + incrementAmount;
        Comparable[] tempArray = new Comparable[expandedSize];
        for(int i= 0; i < sa.length; i++)
        {
            tempArray[i]= sa[i];
        }
        sa  = tempArray;
    }
    for(int i = top; i >= loc; i--)
    {
        sa[i+1] = sa[i];
    }
    sa[loc] = a;
    top++;
}

public void find(Comparable value2){    
    Comparable value = value2;

    if (empty() == true){
        System.out.println("The array is empty");
        Arrays.fill(sa, null);
    }
    else{
    int bsValue = Arrays.binarySearch(sa,value);
    System.out.println("The index is: " + bsValue);
    delete(bsValue);
    }
    }


// This method deletes a given value from the array

public void delete(int bs){
     int location = bs;   
     Comparable[] tempArray = new Comparable[sa.length -1];
     System.arraycopy(sa, 0, tempArray, 0, location);
     if (sa.length != location){
         System.arraycopy(sa, location +1 , tempArray, location, sa.length - location - 1);
         sa = tempArray;
         print();
     }      
}
```

Comment: I think this is a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: What language is this? How is `top` defined? It seems you are indexing past the end of your array at several opportunities: `sa[i+1]` with `i=top`, for example. What is `incrementAmount`?

Comment: Java, initially int top = -1, int incrementAmount = 3 (This is the required amount to expand the array once it is full and you add another item.)

Comment: I found it. Thank you for your help. I had forgot to decrement top after deletion. top--;

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Thank you for your help. I had forgot to decrement top after deletion.

```
public void delete(int bs){
     int location = bs;   
     Comparable[] tempArray = new Comparable[sa.length -1];
     System.arraycopy(sa, 0, tempArray, 0, location);
     if (sa.length != location){
         System.arraycopy(sa, location +1 , tempArray, location, sa.length - location - 1);
         sa = tempArray;
         top--;
         print();
     }
```